# What is the purpose of Logical addresses in operating system? Why they are generated

Tags: operating-system

I want to know that why the CPU generates logical addresses and then maps them into Physical addresses with the help of memory manager? Why do we need them.

Comment: your book or chapter most certainly explains this. Read the explanation and then ask what specifically you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual addresses are required to run several program on a computer.

Assume there is no virtual address mechanism. Compilers and link editors generate a memory layout with a given pattern. Instruction (text segment) are positioned in memory from address 0. Then are the segments for initialized or uninitialized data (data and bss) and the dynamic memory (heap and stack). (see for instance https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-layout-of-c-program/ if you have no idea on memory layout)

When you run this program, it will occupy part of the memory that will no longer be available for other processes in a completely unpredictable way. For instance, addresses 0 to 1M will be occupied, or 0 to 16k, or 0 to 128M, it completely depends on the program characteristics.
If you now want to run concurrently a second program, where will its instructions and data go to memory? Memory addresses are generated by the compiler that obviously do not know at compile time what will be the free memory. And remember memory addresses (for instructions or data) are somehow hard-coded in the program code.

A second problem happens when you want to run many processes and that you run out of memory. In this situations, some processes  are swapped out to disk and restored later. But when restored, a process will go where memory is free and again, it is something that is unpredictable and would require modifying internal addresses of the program.

Virtual memory simplifies all these tasks. When running a process (or restoring it after a swap), the system looks at free memory and fills page tables to create a mapping between virtual addresses (manipulated by the processor and always unchanged) and physical addresses (that depends on the free memory on the computer at a given time).

Answer (score 0):

Logical address translation serves several functions.

One of these is to support the common mapping of a system address space to all processes. This makes it possible for any process to handle interrupt because the system addresses needed to handle interrupts are always in the same place, regardless of the process.

The logical translation system also handles page protection. This makes is possible to protect the common system address space from individual users messing with it. It also allows protecting the user address space, such as making code and data read only, to check for errors.

Logical translation is also a prerequisite for implementing virtual memory. In an virtual memory system, each process's address space is constructed in secondary storage (ie disk). Pages within the address space are brought into memory as needed. This kind of system would be impossible to implement if processes with large address spaces had to be mapped contiguously within memory.